# Several Asynchronous database calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I can't figure out how to do two seperate asynchronous calls and make call1 wait for call2 to have finished, been looking things up, I think I need to use callback or promise, but just don't get it, does anyone have a link to a simple explanation ?
Or can anyone suggest how to adjust my code ?

I have "simplified" the code a bit.

How can I make sure the next record is only read after constructButton has finished ?

```
function justAfunction(){
    var query = "SELECT * FROM trlydp where tdrexr = " + route + " order by tdrseq;";
    try {
        localDB.transaction(function(transaction){

            transaction.executeSql(query, [], function(transaction, results){
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                    var row = results.rows.item(i);

                    constructButton();
                }

            }, function(transaction, error){
                updateStatus("Error: " + error.code + "<br>Message: " + error.message);
            });
        });
    } 
    catch (e) {
        updateStatus("Error: Unable to select data from the db " + e + ".");
    }
}

function constructButton(){

  disabled = false;

  var query = 'SELECT * FROM trlylp';

  //alert(query);
  try {
    localDB.transaction(function(transaction){

      transaction.executeSql(query, [], function(transaction, results){
        alert(results.rows.length);
        if (results.rows.length != 0) {
          disabled = true;
        }

      }, function(transaction, error){
           updateStatus("Error: " + error.code + "<br>Message: " + error.message);
         });
      });
  } 
  catch (e) {
    updateStatus("Error: Unable to select data from the db " + e + ".");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of accomplishing this.

1) One async call should wait for another async call to complete. You can do this by calling the second function in onSuccess() of first one.

2) Make first call synchronous. ( **WHICH is not at all recommeneded** ) as it can potentially make your GUI look hung.

```
function f1(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "blah blah",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(data){
           // do some action based on result
           f2();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I do not think I can use the onSuccess() of the first function, since I am calling the second one in a loop in the first function.

Comment: that's what bro. .you need not call both the functions in the loop. just call the first function whose oncomplete method has a call to function 2. Refer to the example that I gave

Comment: The problem is I use data that I get in the first function, in the second one, if the first one is complete I no longer have the data I want, the way around this would be to store all the retrieved data and use that as a parameter for the second one, can I use data from the first function as a parameter for the second one ?

Comment: If your first function returning the data after ajax call, you can definitely use it bro. In the example I gave in my answer, complete: function(data) has data thats returned from the ajax request from f1(). Got it? In your f2(), you are using the data returned by f1() is what you mean right?

Answer (score -1):

here's how I do it with ajax, but the concept should work for any set of asynchronous work that all needs to complete before continuing:

```
var model = {};

function checkLoadsComplete(){
    if (model.data0 && model.data1 && model.data2){
        //load Complete
        //do something
        return true;
    } else {
        //not done loading
        return false;
    }

}

function getData0(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/data0.json",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(data){
            model.data0 = data;
            checkLoadsComplete();
        }
    })
}

function getData1(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/data1.json",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(data){
            model.data1 = data;
            checkLoadsComplete();
        }
    })
}

function getData2(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/data2.json",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(data){
            model.data2 = data;
            checkLoadsComplete();
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!checkLoadsComplete()){
        getData0();
        getData1();
        getData2();
    }
})
```

Comment: In this approach, number of functions will bloat up if you have to fetch say ten different sql calls. The better way to do it is making sure one function is executed only after the other completes in a chained way.

Comment: Are you advocating using chained anonymous functions? or simply saying the function calls should be called in sequence rather than all at once?

Comment: After another reading it appears you are against defining 10 functions for your 10 calls. You could simply define one template function that takes SQL and the destination object as params.

Comment: Calling functions in sequence wont help, as there is no guarantee in ajax world that funtion f1() completes before execution of f2(). if fi() has an ajax call, then f2() should be called from the onComplete() function of that ajax call.

Comment: Am not against multiple functions, cos they might be doing different things on their own. I am only pointing towards making sure that second function executes only after the first one returns.